# Add to cart url returns invalid url in magento1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, url, addtocart

My add to cart url returns this. When i click it the products doesn't get added because it's invalid. This happens in the homepage.

```
http://localhost/mage/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlL2luZGV4LnBocC9wYWNrYWdlcy9wYWNrYWdlL2luZGV4Lw`,,`/product/13/form_key/D5FhQaqwv69PjG8q/
```

In url "`/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlL2luZGV4LnBocC9wYWNrYWdlcy9wYWNrYWdlL2luZGV4Lw`,,`/`"  =>',,' causing issue.

First in my code it was using `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)` because of this issue i replaced it with this `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)` Still the problem exists.

I clear cache but not working. Anyone have idea?

Comment: Please check form key exist

Answer (score 0):

First, create the product, then pass this product object to the checkout/cart helper to get the add to cart url.

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);//load the product by product id
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuNum);//or load the product by sku number
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuNum);//or load the product from a given store id

echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);//Get the add to cart url
```

and second one is below

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add', array('product'=>$_product->getId(),'qty'=>1, 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>
```

Comment: It's not working I already did.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email_sent',array('null' => true));

foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($value->getEntityId());
    try {
        $order->getSendConfirmation(null);
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
        echo "Order successfully sentn";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```